# Strange error message in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: ssl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, certificate-authority

I was trying to set up a Hyperledger Fabric network because I found the auto set up to be much too opaque. I'm trying to add users to via the Certificate Authority. I'm using Fabric **version 1.4.6**, the latest 1.4 version, I think. Apparently, in production, this is how it would be done anyway.

I created several users. I got into my CLI docker image and tried to register the channel from the example setup from there, but no matter what I do, the response I get is:

```
2020-04-09 20:25:29.301 UTC [main] InitCmd -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/indepedent/admin1/msp: administrators must be declared when no admin ou classification is set
```

Where `admin1` is the user name I choose. I have absolutely no idea what that means. I tried it with a user that had all the roles at the same time. I tried making it a peer. Here, I tried with an admin. I always get this error. Fabric finds this path via:

```
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/indepedent/admin1/msp
```

There are other settings, but this is the one that seems to affect it. The root certificate is set via:

```
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts/tls-cert.pem
```

That's the one that was generated when I created the certificate authority server. There was also a `ca-cert.pem`, but this seems to be the one Fabric wants.

Does anyone know what this error message means? I looked it up, but I couldn't find any usable information about it.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message it seems that you have not enabled the NodeOUs. When those are disabled, Fabric expects that the MSP you are mounting has an `admincerts` folder in it.

For solution, assuming that your `admin1` identity is an `admin` user for the organization, do the following:

1. Create `admincerts` folder inside `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH` directory.
2. Copy the certificate from `signcerts` folder inside the same directory to `admincerts` folder.

Comment: I'm using Amazon Managed Blockchain and it solved my problem. I had deleted the `admincerts` folder because in the docs it's said that this folder is deprecated since Fabric v1.4.3. Also, could you please provide more info on your solution?

Reference: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/membership/membership.html#msp-structure